# confusion about mapreduce.job.cache.files when using DistributedCache

Tags: hadoop

when I using  Hadoop  DistributedCache, I found some other jars including in **mapreduce.job.cache.files** while I am not directly add.

Like this ,My addFileToClassPath on **hdfs://halcluster/user/****/lib**, But I found jars which include path like

> hdfs://hacluster/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/ldapuser/.staging/job_1490857857916_***/libjars/xxx.jar.

I don't add this path from DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath.
Why this path is included in the configuration which key is mapreduce.job.cache.files and tmpjars?